# ajax posting is shown as red color in firebug console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

If i execute the following code ,then i enabled the firebug.In firebug while submitting form ,in console the "post to login_submit.php" is shown as a red color.And i also didnt get any response too.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js">
        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js">
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-popover.js">
</script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery.fn.extend(
    {
    scrollToMe: function () {
        var x = jQuery(this).offset().top - 100;
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x}, 500);
      }
    }
  );

  function show_error(id_wth_hash, Message) {
    alert(id_wth_hash);
    alert(Message);

    //$("*[id]").popover('hide');

    //   $("[id^='id_*']").popover('hide');
    //    $("[id^='id_*']").popover('hide');
    // $("#id*").popover('hide');



    /*  var oArr = {};
   $("*[id]").each(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   if (!oArr[id]) oArr[id] = true;
   });
   for (var prop in oArr)
   alert(prop); */



    //  alert(id_wth_hash);

    $(id_wth_hash).popover({title: "<B style='color:red'>Error<\/B>", content: Message, placement: 'left'});
    var popovertemp = $(id_wth_hash).data('popover');
    popovertemp.options.content = Message;
    $(id_wth_hash).popover('show');
    //$("*[id]").not(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
    // $.not(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
    $(id_wth_hash).focus();
    //$(id_wth_hash).scrollTop($('a#captchaAnchor').position().top)

    //$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(id_wth_hash).offset().top }, 500);

    $(id_wth_hash).scrollToMe();

    /* $(id_wth_hash).focus(function() {
        $(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
    });
   */
    $(id_wth_hash).bind("keyup input paste", function()
      {
        //Do Work Here
        $(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
      }
    );


    $(id_wth_hash).click(function()
      {
        $(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
      }
    );



    $(id_wth_hash).hover(function()
      {
        $(id_wth_hash).popover('hide');
      }
    );




  }

  $(function()
    {

      //show_error('#id_txt_user','I Have passed the value');


      $("#pwd_login").tooltip({title: 'Min.6 Characters , 1 number ,1 lowercase ,1 UpperCase,  1 Symbol are expected', placement: 'right'});
      $("#user_login").tooltip({title: 'Registered Email', placement: 'right'});






    }
  );



        function submit_login_form()
        {
        var action = "login_submit.php";

            $.ajax(
              {
              url: 'login_submit.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: $('#login').serialize(),
              success: function(data_in) 
                {
                  alert(data_in);
                  if (data_in !== null && !isEmpty(data_in) && (data_in).indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR') !== -1)
                  {
                    var value = data_in.substr(data_in.indexOf('VALIDATION_ERROR'), data_in.indexOf('|#END#'));
                    var array_str = value.split('|');
                    var id_val = "#id_" + array_str[1].trim();
                    show_error(id_val, array_str[2]);
                  } else 
                  {
                    window.location.replace('jb_organization_regn_confirm.html');
                  }
                }
              }
            );
            return false;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="login_submit.php" id="login">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        Email<input value="" name="user_email" id="user_login"><br>
        Password<input value="" name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd_login"><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me">Stay Signed In<br>
        <input type="submit" value="login" onclick="submit_login_form()">  
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

The below one is my login_submit.php

```
<?php require 'db.php'; ?>
<?php require 'shopping_user_class.php'; ?>
<?php 
$error_op = " START ";
$obj_shopping_login = new user;
//$obj_shopping_login->shopping_user_name = "";
$obj_shopping_login->shopping_user_pwd = "";
$obj_shopping_login->shopping_user_email = "";
$obj_shopping_login->remember_me = "";
function Collect_all_form_variables() {
    global $obj_shopping_login;
    global $error_op;

    try {

        $obj_shopping_login->shopping_user_email = $_POST["user_email"];
        $obj_shopping_login->shopping_user_pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

        if (isset($_POST['remember_me']) &&
                $_POST['remember_me'] == 'yes') {
            $obj_shopping_login->remember_me = 'yes';
        } else {
            $obj_shopping_login->remember_me = 'no';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $error_op = 'Collect_all_form_variables' . $error_op . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
function check_useremail_and_password($current_user_email,$current_user_pwd) {
    global $error_op;


    try {
        global $pdo;



        $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from photostudio.user WHERE  UPPER(email) =  UPPER(:current_user_email) AND pwd=:current_user_pwd");

// Execute the query, replacing the placeholders with their true value
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':current_user_email' => trim($current_user_email),
            ':current_user_pwd'=>current_user_pwd
        ));

        if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $error_op = 'check_useremail_and_password ' . $error_op . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return true;
}
function validate_form_stage1() {

//alert("please");
    $required = array('user_email', 'pwd');

// Loop over field names, make sure each one exists and is not empty
    $error = false;
    foreach ($required as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $error = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        return "VALIDATION_ERROR|" . $field . "|Value is Required|#END#";
    } else {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
} 
function process_request() {


    global $obj_shopping_login;

    global $error_op;

    $all_values_are_present = validate_form_stage1();

    if (substr($all_values_are_present, 0, 16) === "VALIDATION_ERROR") {


        echo $all_values_are_present;
        return false;
    }

    Collect_all_form_variables();
    if (check_useremail_and_password() == true) {

        echo "Success" . $error_op;


    } else {

        echo "Failed" . $error_op;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Run it with Fiddler2 running so you get full details of any failures (which is presumably the cause of the red log entry).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ajax posting is shown as red color in firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590935/ajax-posting-is-shown-as-red-color-in-firebug)

Comment: you should really see some more info when you click on that red network line - headers, response etc.

Comment: any more details than just red, does it give an error like not found etc. Does you php file sit in the same directory as your ajax code ?

Comment: Also if you cntrl click on the red link it should load the page in a new tab. Does the page load if it shows and error what error :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter if i click that i have only header,post,cookies and no response

Comment: that most probably means you have a server problem - check the header if your server is not returning Error 500 and check your server logs... state like this usually comes from an incorrect `.htaccess` setup

Comment: Nothing to do with the server. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the form is submitting and it is causing the http connection to be cut off. Cancel the submission of the form.

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

Ideally you would be calling your function onsubmit of the form and not click of the button.